# DropWizard: Why is it ignoring a connection if flooded with 100 requests?

Tags: java, performance, http, connection-pooling, dropwizard

We have Gatling tests (mis)used for integration testing. 
One of things it does at one place is that it shoots 100 HTTP requests *at the same instant* to the tested service, based on DropWizard 1.3.5.

Before upgrading from DropWizard 0.9.5, this worked fine.

But now, these requests end up with `ConnectException` on the client side, and I don't see any errors on the server side - the requests is silently ignored by DropWizard. I also looked at the pools over JMX and don't see these hanging anywhere. It looks as if the server lost track of the socket and never sent a response or "hanged up".

```
java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: somehost.mycompany.net/10.103.66.45:9000
```

I have looked at the [DropWizard config reference](https://www.dropwizard.io/1.3.1/docs/manual/configuration.html). I don't see any fine tuning of what's rejected and when. Here is my current config:

```
server:
  maxThreads: 64
  maxQueuedRequests: 1024
  adminMaxThreads: 8
  ...
database:
  url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/mydb
  poolInitialSize: 20
  poolMaxSize: 100
```

I am including the DB pool size because it might be that it gathers the resources for the request handling IoC, but 100 should cover all Dw threads.

I would expect the extra requests to wait in the queue (which AFAIK should be handled on the OS side, since the new IO API is used) and taken by the 64 threads.

What's interesting is that before I set the `maxThreads` to 64, the default of 1024 applied; and then, sometimes the tests passed, sometimes not.

My question is:
Does DropWizard do this intentionally (a DoS detection)?
If yes, how do I configure it?
If not, well, then that's a bug.

Comment: is it timeout to connect or timeout to read ? if time out to read - did your app service response time increase ?

Comment: @JigarJoshi,  ConnectException. I wrote `TimeoutException`, but is actually Gatling wrapper, which confused me. Edited.